# Android Change spinner pressed colour Light Holo theme

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am working on an Android Tablet app. I have created a custom action bar, and managed to style it the way I want, except for the spinners.

My main theme extends Holo Light meaning that when I press a spinner it goes blue. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a custom style for `android:actionDropDownStyle` in your theme which itself has an `android:background` for your custom state-list drawable.

Here's the one that's specified by default:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_disabled_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_pressed_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_ab_default_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

You'll need to provide your own images for each one of these states (and for mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi).

You can modify the ones that come with the platform to make your life easier. Look in `SDK/platforms/platform-14/data/res/` in the `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, and `drawable-xhdpi` folders.

Comment: I added the following to my theme <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MySpinner</item>

Then created 

        <!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
<style name="MySpinner" >
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
</style>

This did not seem to work. When adding the spin_background drawable as a background to a spinner in an xml layout it works. So I can rule out a problem with the drawable.